# How to make my tmux which starts via crontab @reboot use bash?

Tags: bash, shell, tmux, defaults

I have a crontab which launches tmux-launching-script as follows :

```
-sh-3.00# crontab -l
@reboot /root/scripts/tmux_autostart.sh
```

where

```
#!/bin/bash
# setup tmux session

tmux new -d -s my_session
```

but when the system boots I don't have my regular prompt but **shell** prompt :

```
-sh-3.00#
```

how to change it to bash if I already have this in my config **.tmux.conf**

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/bash
```

**EDIT**

```
-sh-3.00# cat /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@reboot` job is in root's crontab. The variables set in a crontab only apply in this crontab, so the settings in `/etc/crontab` have no influence on the job executed by root's crontab.

The default shell in Cron is `/bin/sh`, and the `SHELL` environment variable is set to `/bin/sh` unless overridden. So Tmux starts with `SHELL=/bin/sh`.

It appears that your `/bin/sh` is Bash 3.00. The prompt indicates that bash was started as a login shell, and that no initialization file set `PS1` (there was probably no initialization file at all).

If you set `default-shell` in `~/.tmux.conf`, this takes precedence over the `SHELL` environment variable. I suspect you aren't showing `.tmux.conf` in root's home directory but in some other location, maybe your own home directory.

You have a choice of setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` in root's crontab, or writing a `.tmux.conf` file in root's home directory.

Answer (score 2):

### cron

Instead of doing this as a @reboot, what if you restructured things slightly so that it was say every few minutes, and did a check to see if tmux was already running, if not, then call your `tmux_autostart.sh`.

#### Example

Every 5 minutes run to see if `tmux_autostart.sh` is running. For starters a test like this will see if `tmux_autostart.sh` is up:

```
# down
$ ps -eaf|grep -q "[t]mux_autostart.sh"
$ echo $?
1

# up
$ ps -eaf|grep -q "[t]mux_autostart.sh"
$ echo $?
0
```

We can then use this above test like so in our cron:

```
*/5 * * * *  ps -eaf|grep -q "[t]mux_autostart.sh" && /root/scripts/tmux_autostart.sh
```

### xinitrc

If you're only interested in starting this up when you login I believe you could put your script in the file `$HOME/.xintrc`. Then it will run when you login.

Comment: Besides running a crontab every few minutes being a horrible way to run something at boot time (why do I sometimes not find my tmux session when I log in shortly after boot? Why is my disk waking up every 5 minutes?), how is it supposed to help? Whether it's `*/5 * * * *` or `@reboot` doesn't change the value of `SHELL` or `HOME`.

Comment: @Gilles - is it a optimal solution? Of course not, but so what if something like a `ps | grep` runs every five minutes. Modern day systems can "handle" it. Also the OP shows  `crontab -l`, which I see has a hash prompt `#`, so maybe it's root, but my experience says a `crontab -l` is typically a user's crontab entry. In those I would expect them to run as the user so I would expect the `SHELL` and `HOME` to be set for them then.

Comment: My point is that it doesn't matter when the crontab entry runs anyway, changing from `@reboot` to a time won't fix his problem. You're working around something that isn't a problem (the use of `@crontab`) without tackling the real problem (`SHELL` not set to the expected value, presumably because it's set in `/etc/crontab` and Patryk expected it to also take efect in user crontabs).

Comment: I think it should be `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is one way to do it by using such a cronjob:

```
@reboot . $HOME/profile; /root/scripts/tmux_autostart.sh
```